# How can I use custom builders that generate .cpp and .h files?

Tags: c++, build, scons

My project is only composed by two files:

```
text.foo
main.cpp
```

main.cpp code looks like this:

```
#include "foo.h"
#include "bar.h"

int main()
{
 ...
}
```

I have a custom builder that takes as input `text.foo` and generates as output the following files:

```
foo.h
bar.h
text.cpp
```

`text.cpp` must be compiled to produce `text.o`, which in turn must be linked together to `main.o` to produce the final executable. The `.h` files are a dependency of `main.cpp`. I need to write a SConstruct file that ensures the following:

1. `.h` files must be generated before main.cpp is compiled
2. when `text.foo` is changed, the `.h` files must be regenerated
   before `main.cpp` is compiled

I'm playing around with Builder and Emitters but I seem unable to obtain points 1 and 2.
Ideally I'd like to have the following line in the SConstruct file:

```
Program('myProgram', ["main.cpp", "text.foo"])
```

Comment: So far, my application that generates programs prompts the User with forms to fill out for functions and classes.  The application then generates the appropriate source and header files.  I try to hard code as little as possible.  Use configuration files.

Comment: Please show how your custom builder looks like, and also the current version of your SConstruct (MWE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need a builder that knows how to build text.cpp and so on from text.foo

It's a little tricky because you generate multiple files from your text.foo with no relationship. However, your emitter for your builder should state it's creating foo.h, bar.h and text.cpp

Then you merely need

```
Program('myprogram', ['main.cpp', 'test.cpp'])
```

And you're done, as scons will note main.cpp requires foo.h to build, and will find it has a way of generating foo.h, and test.cpp, and will generate them.